# WebStorm: React + Bootstrap autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, react-bootstrap

I've installed React + Bootstrap in WebStorm. JSX works, everything is fine but Bootstrap code highlighting doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in 2020.3

[image]

what IDE and `react-bootstrap` versions do you use? Can be [WEB-46445](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-46445) that is fixed in 2020.2.1

Comment: Thanks a log for tip. It was a bug my Webstorm version 2020.1. Now all works perfect.